# Application directory must exist and be a directory (Java + Eclipse + GAE)

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I am trying to create Google App Engine module in eclipse using java.
What I have done is following https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/webtoolsplatform and https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/

I have created the dynamic web project and enterprise application project.

But i have problem when assigning module to EAR. In **Google App Engine > Deployment property page**, I only got this following options : [image]

instead of :

[image]

So I try to add the module manually, via application.xml, and create *default* folder containing appengine-web.xml for that module.

So my folder hierarchy looks like this

[image]

Now, when I tried to start the server, I got this following error:

> INFO: Application directory 'D:\Project.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\ZEARProject\default' must exist and be a directory.
>   com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineConfigException: Invalid configuration
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.reportDeferredConfigurationException(DevAppServerImpl.java:446)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.doStart(DevAppServerImpl.java:226)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.access$000(DevAppServerImpl.java:47)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:213)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:211)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:211)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:277)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.run(DevAppServerMain.java:219)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:210)
>   Caused by: com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineConfigException: Application directory 'D:\Project.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\ZEARProject\default' must exist and be a directory.
>       at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.EarHelper.reportConfigException(EarHelper.java:91)
>       at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.EarHelper.getApplicationDirectory(EarHelper.java:184)
>       at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.EarHelper.readEarInfo(EarHelper.java:115)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApplicationConfigurationManager.readEarConfiguration(ApplicationConfigurationManager.java:190)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApplicationConfigurationManager.(ApplicationConfigurationManager.java:137)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApplicationConfigurationManager.newEarConfigurationManager(ApplicationConfigurationManager.java:60)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.(DevAppServerImpl.java:132)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.doCreateDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:258)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.access$000(DevAppServerFactory.java:36)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$1.run(DevAppServerFactory.java:226)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$1.run(DevAppServerFactory.java:224)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.createDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:224)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.createDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:94)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:265)
>       ... 3 more

Can somebody help me?? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

After you create the EAR project, create Dynamic Web project for each module. In the New Dynamic Web Project wizard you will get the option to add it to as a module in another EAR project. When done you will see the second screen for each module.

Note that the EAR and its modules do not need to be in folder hierarchy as mentioned in the documentation.